# Crate for validating received data from an other host

Tags: rust

In my application I receive lots of different messages from multiple hosts. Sometimes these messages contain invalid data (like floats contain INF/NAN). So I need to validate these messages before using them.

Implementing `fn validate(&self) -> bool` on each of these messages manually is very tiresome. Does somebody know any crate which I can make use of to automate this process?

```
trait Validator {
    fn validate(&self) -> bool;
}

struct Message1 {
    a: f64,
    b: i32,
    c: f32,
}

impl Validator for Message1 {
    fn validate(&self) -> bool {
        if !f64::is_finite(self.a) {
            return false;
        }
        if !f32::is_finite(self.c) {
            return false;
        }
        
        true
    }
}

struct Message2 {
    a: [f64; 100],
}

impl Validator for Message2 {
    fn validate(&self) -> bool {
        for d in self.a {
            if !f64::is_finite(d) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        true
    }
}

fn main() {

}
```

Comment: You can make serde do this, but you'd put it into the deserialization part, which isn't included here.

Comment: I'm planning to make use of `bincode` crate (binary format serializer) to do serialization and deserialization. Will this help? https://docs.rs/bincode/2.0.0-rc.3/bincode/index.html

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to make this work with a `Decode` impl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [bincode 2](https://docs.rs/bincode/2.0.0-rc.3), you can combine the validation into bincode's deserialization step.

First, make a type for your floats.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Encode)]
pub struct NonNanF64(f64);
```

Then make the validation. I'm using `TryFrom<f64>` since this will let you use `try_into`. It would also be sensible to use a real error type instead of `()`, which I'm using here for conciseness.

```rust
impl TryFrom<f64> for NonNanF64 {
    type Error = ();

    fn try_from(value: f64) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if value.is_nan() {
            Err(())
        } else {
            Ok(Self(value))
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can implement `bincode::Decode`. This just decodes an `f64` and tries to convert it to `NonNanF64`. You also need `bincode::BorrowDecode` which is nearly the same.

```rust
impl Decode for NonNanF64 {
    fn decode<D: Decoder>(decoder: &mut D) -> Result<Self, DecodeError> {
        let num: f64 = Decode::decode(decoder)?;
        num.try_into()
            .map_err(|()| DecodeError::Other("float was NaN"))
    }
}

impl<'de> BorrowDecode<'de> for NonNanF64 {
    fn borrow_decode<D: BorrowDecoder<'de>>(decoder: &mut D) -> Result<Self, DecodeError> {
        let num: f64 = BorrowDecode::borrow_decode(decoder)?;
        num.try_into()
            .map_err(|()| DecodeError::Other("float was NaN"))
    }
}
```

And now, you can use this type in any message struct that derives `Decode`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Decode, Encode)]
struct Message2 {
    a: [NonNanF64; 100],
}
```

I've also derived `Encode` for both `Message2` and `NonNanF64` since bincode encodes structs with one field the same way as the field itself.

You also need a way to retrieve the contents of `NonNanF64`.

```rust
impl From<NonNanF64> for f64 {
    fn from(value: NonNanF64) -> Self {
        value.0
    }
}
```

This lets you use `into` to convert to `f64`.

You can also do this process for `f32`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Encode)]
pub struct NonNanF32(f32);

// etc
```

Then you can construct `Message1` with both of them.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Decode, Encode)]
pub struct Message1 {
    pub a: NonNanF64,
    pub b: i32,
    pub c: NonNanF32,
}
```

Now of course, this isn't ideal, since now your struct doesn't hold an actual `f64`, and you need to call a method to get the value. Serde is more elegant, since you can specify a conversion to the `Deserialize` macro, which would let you have your message structs contain a real `f64`.

But on the other hand, having your `f64` in a wrapper helps to ensure this float is never `NaN` throughout the code instead of just at serialization.

[Here's the whole thing on playground, but it doesn't compile since the playground doesn't have bincode.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2e9eac8f3663c8b0f61d25a33379bcf)